Как курсор детектит границы кнопки с clipPath, через коллизию?
Пытаюсь сделать свою первую игру про астероиды. Корабль сталкивается с астероидами и игра завершается (без физики), а на них clipPath = polygon для задания неправильной формы.
Задал изменение цвета при наведении на них, и курсор идеально реагирует на весть кривой путь астероида. Как он это делает?
Посмотрел код для коллизии полигонов, это ещё слишком сложно для меня.
Я подумал, может можно на мой корабль разместить точки выполняющие функцию курсора, и ненужно будет писать код коллизии? )

То что вы предложили - это не всегда будет работать, потому что полигоны могут пересекаться рёбрами
Вы можете пройтись по всем отрезкам первого и второго полигона и проверить пересекается ли хоть один отрезок первого полигона с каким-либо отрезком второго полигона (тут есть очень простой алгоритм)
